# Which type uses more space on disk in Neo4J: boolean or int 0/1?

Tags: types, neo4j

I am just wondering about the size of data types on disk.

We need a flag for (potentially) a lot of nodes, it is a boolean (0|1) flag. So I would use a short key.

#### Should I use boolean (true|false) or numeric (1|0) value for this in order to save space on disc?

[This page](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/values/) is crucial for this topic, but is does not say much regarding used space, bits and bytes:

> The property types:
>
> - Number, an abstract type, which has the subtypes Integer and Float
> - String
> - Boolean

#### Java Driver

I can get *int*, *long*, *number* and *boolean* by using the [Java Driver](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/Value.html). But I have no clue, which one is indicated in which case and what they mean exactly regarding their size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking what we call a boolean (*true*/*false*) will be then stored  with a single bit, meanwhile an integer can vary in size, but often the "normal" *int* value takes 32bit.

So, if you just need to have a property as a flag I highly suggest to use the *Boolean* type.

If you want to lean more also take a look at this [Neo4j doc page](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/java-embedded/property-values/), it might helps

Comment: This page is very close to what I have looked for. :)

Comment: Glad to helped you out!